# convert nested json to dict

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Im trying to send the Json below with Scrapy

```
{
"version": 1,
"message_type": 104,
"message_id": 14,
"body": [
{
  "message_type": 104,
  "chat_message": {
    "mssg": "hello",
    "message_type": 1,
    "uid": "15373703487091",
    "from_person_id": "5134266921",
    "to_person_id": "3093543561",
    "read": false
  }
}
],
"is_background": false
}
```

I've tried to send it hard coded like this

```
self.postRequest = {"version":"1",
                    "message_type":"104",
                    "message_id":"18",
                    "body":"[{'message_type':'104','chat_message':{'mssg':'hello','message_type':'1','uid':'15372201045381','from_person_id':'5134266921','to_person_id':'3093543561','read':'false'}}]",
                        "is_background":"false"}

yield FormRequest(url=response.url   , formdata=self.postRequest, callback=self.parse_data,dont_filter=True, headers=self.params, cookies=self.cookies)
```

i get HTTP 200 status with an error message : Unknown command server_unknown_action.

so i dont know if i did something wrong with the json structure or the error is elsewhere

Comment: Try using your json itself as a dict. You don't need to change it to string for body. And I'm assuming `false` should be boolean so it would become `False`.

Comment: well i have already tried to remove the double quotes, but i got an error : TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got dict. seems like it dosent like a nested dicts

Comment: Have you tried `json.dumps(dict)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormRequest` class is for sending data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Sending JSON as a POST body likely means you really want to send `Content-Type: application/json`.

For this, use the normal `Request` class, with `method` set to `POST`, and `json.dumps()` your `self.postRequest`-data into the `Request().body`.

```py
yield Request(url=response.url,
              method='POST',
              headers={
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
              },
              body=json.dumps(self.postRequest),
              callback=self.parse_data,
              dont_filter=True,
              cookies=self.cookies)
```